# How to use cte in bigquery where clause

Tags: google-bigquery, common-table-expression

I have a query which takes value of cte for filtering.

```
with cte1 as (
  select 1 as id
)

select 
  count(*)
from dataset.table1
where
 id= (select id from cte1 limit 1)
```

The query does not work in above case. But If I hardcode `where id=1`, it works. What am I missing here?

Comment: works for me. are you getting any error? what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: It gives 0 count despite having multiple id with value 1.

Comment: Hmm, the question that I posted actually works, now I realize. I was trying to generalize the issue I had. 

Actually I had a date partitioned table. I was trying to use metadata of the table `dataset.__TABLES__` to get the last_modified_time as timestamp in cte. And then use that value to get all the data from latest partition. But it didnot work.

Comment: To obtain an overview of the partition, please use `dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS`. The modification date of a table can be slightly later than  the last entry due to processing time.

Answer (score 1):

The given example should work. However, the `limit 1` may cause some problems if there are more than one entry on the `cte1` table.

```
with cte1 as (
  select 1 as id
  union all select 2
),
example as  (Select id from unnest([1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]) as id)

select 
  #count(*)
  *
from example # dataset.table1
where
 #id= (select id from cte1 limit 1)
  id in (select distinct id from cte1 )
```

Comment: Hmm, the question that I posted actually works, now I realize. I was trying to generalize the issue I had. 

Actually I had a date partitioned table. I was trying to use metadata of the table `dataset.__TABLES__` to get the last_modified_time as timestamp in cte. And then use that value in where clause to get all the data from latest partition. But it didnot work.